# Availability test dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have some endpoints in Azure that I need to test for availability and present in some kind of health check dashboard. I have set up some availability tests in an Application Insights instance but I am struggling to represent this in some kind of a dashboard.

So far I have looked at Kusto queries and I can pin chart result to an Azure shared dashboard but it is quite limited and not suitable for representation of health checks. It would be the best if solution was in Azure, I am aware that there are commercial solutions for this.

As I haven't built something like this before, any advice is welcome.

I ended up with creating some workbooks, queried availability results and visualized it with tiles that I pin to a dashboard. Now I have to figure out dashboard sharing.

Comment: Limited in what way? What are your requirements?

Comment: if your web app runs in multi instances(if you specify the scale rules), for Health check, if an instance fails to respond to the ping, the system determines it is unhealthy and removes it from the load balancer rotation. This increases your application’s average availability and resiliency.

Availability-test in Application Insights does not do such thing, it just checks the health.

Comment: @Zare  AFAIK, Since the availability test has two parameters in common, we can form a graph between time and availability. The remaining parameters change with resources.

Comment: @PeterBons availability test results seamed limited for presentation but a colleague helped me set up visualizations with tiles and I created some workbooks which are now pinned to a dashboard.

Comment: How do you add 1 single Availability Test to the Dashboard? With Availability Test Summary widget you get ALL of your Standard Tests aggregated on the widget. What if I want to have a single one?

Answer (score 0):

If your web application runs in several instances, the system will do a health check and remove any instances that don't respond to pings from the load balancer rotation if they are deemed unhealthy. The average availability and resilience of your application are improved as a result. Application Insights' availability test doesn't carry out such actions; it merely examines the system's health.

- Enabled the availability test with the URL for every respective domain, like the image shown below.

[image]

- I accessed every URL to trace the availability of the app.

[image]

- The images below show the results of availability test logs.

[image]

[image]

While moving the chart Since the availability test has two parameters in common, we can form a graph between time and availability or size. The remaining parameters change with resources.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Sampath but we really need just the result of those tests to see that apps are alive and ready, I know there are more advanced features such as you mentioned.